# ATTiny1606 Timer TCA0 interrupt not triggering

Tags: c, interrupt, avr

Rather i can´t see the mistake or there is a bug in the compiler ;-). I´m trying to use `TCA0` on an `ATTiny1606` to generate a PWM to dim some leds. The problem is that the interrupts are never getting called. The System runs at the interal osciallator @ 20MHz and is configured correctly.

**TCA0 configuration**

```c
int main(void)
{
    // ...

    TCA0.SINGLE.PER = 0xFFFF;
    TCA0.SINGLE.CMP0 = 0x1FFF;
    TCA0.SINGLE.INTCTRL = TCA_SINGLE_OVF_bm | TCA_SINGLE_CMP0_bm;
    TCA0.SINGLE.CTRLB = TCA_SINGLE_WGMODE_SINGLESLOPE_gc;
    TCA0.SINGLE.CTRLA = TCA_SINGLE_CLKSEL_DIV2_gc | TCA_SINGLE_ENABLE_bm;
    
    sei();
    
    // ...
    
    while (1)
    {
        // ...
    }
}
```

**Interrupt routines**

```c
ISR(TCA0_OVF_vect)
{
    PORTA.OUTCLR = PIN6_bm;
    TCA0.SINGLE.INTFLAGS = TCA_SINGLE_OVF_bm;
}

ISR(TCA0_CMP0_vect)
{
    PORTA.OUTSET = PIN6_bm;
    TCA0.SINGLE.INTFLAGS = TCA_SINGLE_CMP0_bm;
}
```

The interrupts are never called. Even if i put a delay inside (I know this never should be done) for testing purpose the program is still running. So maybe i forget to set some bit in the control registers or what am I missing?

Comment: How do you know that interrupts never get triggered? If you don't have a logic analyser or scope, change clock select to `TCA_SINGLE_CLKSEL_DIV1024_gc` and connect an LED to PA6 (if you have not done so yet) so that you can visually observe it.

Comment: There is no signal on PA6 or any other output i configured. I Also tried different prescalers and settings!

Comment: Did you setup the PA6 as an output with `PORTA.DIR = PIN6_bm;` then? or please provide your complete configuration code.

Comment: @hcheung Thanks for your help. Everything was setup correctly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry to bother you, but due to a configuration error the interrupts were not set correctly at compile time. The problem was not the preprocessor, compiler or any other thing. The problem was the user in front of the screen. After lots of time debugging the code and the assembly i found a mistake in my configuration:

[image: Microchip Studio configuration]

When I created the project, I selected the wrong microcontroller (`ATTiny406` instead of `ATTiny1606`). What a mess! Now everything is working fine and the interrups are called correctly.

> I won't delete the question. Maybe it will help someone with the same error!

Thanks a lot for helping [@hcheung](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4902099/hcheung)